# How secure is read-only mode for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have problem's with viruses and backdoors on my wordpress sites.
I decided that it will be good to put all wordpress files into read-only mode and to do manually updates. All wp-content into another web-server for static content.

**I think if hacker can't upload shell he can't connect to services directly(???)**. There are ways to inject evil code:

1. Loged-in wordpress & edit post with javascript or some similar things. I will prevent execution of php inside widget's. Bruteforce limit & another firewall.
2. Access to database server throw 0-day exploits on wordpress & do something on it to write into RW part of /
3. Hack other service (mail/ftp) & write backdoor into webroot, change setting's of web-server

**My question is:** from what kind of attacks RO mode on wordpress engine couldn't help? and how to secure wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might not be from Wordpress. It might be the server is malconfigured, you're uploading malicious files to the server, or the plugins. What makes you think it's Wordpress?

Comment: Because sometimes updates weren't on time. PS: I have backdoor on site where weren't plugin's and I didn't upload anything. I just want use stable version =) PS: It's not a question about wordpress good or not in security. It's about influence of RO-mode on all PHP files of wordpress site.